# Is there a query or a page where I can see the details of my cost specific to Bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cost-management

I can see my total BigQuery cost from the "billing" section.

However, I need to see data such as,

- Which table costs me how much? I mean, I need to see the cost of each table individually.
- How much cost has been created by the queries made to that table in the last month?
  etc.

I would be very happy if you could help with this. I have too many tables to calculate the cost based on the dimensions of the individual tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have published an article about [Reducing your BigQuery bills with BI Engine capacity orchestration](https://medium.com/p/9e2634c84a82)

which features a query like:

```
DECLARE var_day STRING DEFAULT '2021-09-09';
SELECT
  protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.createTime,
  round(5* (protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.totalProcessedBytes/POWER(2,40) ),2) AS processedBytesCostProjection,
  round(5* (protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.totalBilledBytes/POWER(2,40) ),2) AS billedBytesCostInUSD
FROM
  `<dataset_auditlogs>.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= var_day and protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.createTime>=TIMESTAMP(var_day)
  AND protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.eventName="query_job_completed"
  AND protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.totalProcessedBytes IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics. totalProcessedBytes DESC
```

The query uses a flat rate of 5 USD to calculate the cost of a 1TB on-demand query according to the GCP costs table.

The output is this:

[image]

by adding another column:

`protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.query`

you will get the raw query that you can use to optimize your query.

If you want to go further you can use

`...job.jobStatistics.referencedTables` that lists ALL the tables the query touches to actually see and do some filtering on the tables you want.

the json view helps you to identify the right attribute to query and filter on